# KMS Host has more than the minimum count, but client machines are still not activating

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, activation, kms

So pretty as the question states, here is some more info:

What I have done:

1) I have setup 36 machines (I have more, but just done one lab for now) to point to the KMS Host

2) I have rearmed the host and again setup the 36 machines

3) The KMS Host is a 2012R2 machines

4) The clients are all Windows 7 enterprise and there are 3 2012R2 and 1 2008R2 server part of this pool

5) I have disabled and re-enabled the firewall

6) I have checked and confirmed my dns settings

7) I can ping the KMS host machine from the clients

The images below show that I have the numbers, but I am still getting the insufficient count message.

From the KMS Host:

[image]

From a client Machine:

[image]

The host key I have installed is for 2012R2-Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Just thought to follow up this question with an answer :-)

I was looking at the wrong count:
I was looking at the "Total requests received" instead of the "Current Count"

The reason the Current Count is not increasing is because I forgot to set the generalize option during my sysprep so all the CMID's where the same and not unique like they need to be for the count to increase.